# Passing variables in a JavaScript ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Test View that is making an ajax call to a Test Controller. The problem I'm having is in accessing the variables to send to the controller. Here's my code:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "@Url.Action("Copy", "Test")",
            data: { folderName: @ViewBag.SampleProjectName },
            success: function (returnData) {
                if (!returnData) {
                    return;
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                return;
            }
        });
```

Running this code results in a runtime error stating that 'FileHandling' is not defined.

I *believe* what's happening is that the value is not being passed as a string

I say this because if I hard-code the value as a string, it works:

```
            data: { folderName: "FileHandling" },
```

How can I access either a query string parameter or a ViewBag property to pass as folderName?

Comment: Put quoutation marks around `@ViewBag.SampleProjectName`like you did with `"@Url.Action("Copy", "Test")"`

Comment: Please add the MVC framework you're using to the tags. All that @ stuff is not Javascript.

Comment: Look at the generated source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's because you're missing quotes.

So your code should be: `data: { folderName: "@ViewBag.SampleProjectName" },`

After all, when you're enclosing `url` in quotes, why not `folderName`?

Comment: I thought that putting my variable in quotes would pass the literal "@ViewBag.SampleProjectName" instead of its value.

Comment: @StraxTillbaka But you're passing `@url...` in quotes too. Why should it behave differently?

Comment: The original code I copied didn't use quotes and I misunderstood how it was working in trying to get mine to work. Anyway, thanks much for the help.